# IQR based outlier detection with multivariate data

Tags: multivariate-analysis, outliers, interquartile

One method to detect outliers in a dataset $[x_1 ... x_N], x_i \in R$ consists in finding the samples $x_i$ such that
$$ x_i \lt Q_1-K*IQR | x_i \gt Q3 + K*IQR $$
where $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ are the first and third quartile, respectively, $IQR$ is the interquartile range and $K$ is a constant (e.g. 1.5). How can this method be applied to multivariate dataset $[x_1 ... x_N], x_i \in R^k$ , with a high number of dimensions (e.g. k > 100)?

Answer (score 1):

Detecting outliers can be done through univariate or multivariate frameworks. I recommend, detecting extreme outliers (also called global filtering) is better to be done via IQR with a univariate approach while detecting local/spatial outliers is better to be done with a multivariate/multidimensional fashion through density-based algorithms.

#### Edited:

Adding another point to complete the answer!
The choice of the algorithm is highly dependent on the sample size and heterogeneity characteristic of your data!

Comment: What is the principle behind deletion of outliers?  Why risk having your results non-prospectively-applicable, i.e., not applying to future data that may contain "outliers"?

Comment: Outliers leads to the violation of underlying structure in your data. Hence results into  biased decisions. 
TO your second question, this is absolutely depend on your application. If you need a streaming outlier detection algorithm, then it is recommended to go with machine learning approaches which are regression outlier based not Hawkins outlier.

Comment: But any definition of "outlier" is arbitrary and will limit generalizability.  Better to use robust statistical methods not hurt by "outliers".

Comment: Good point. Can you name some cool robust statistical methods for finding local outliers?

Comment: No, I'm not referring to robust outlier detection.   I was referring to robust estimators / model fitting methods so that results are meaningful whether "outliers" are present or not.

Comment: All of them estimating some properties. The choice of which approach to take is application specific. E.g., if you need perspective analysis on your data then you definitely go with model fitting and residual analysis etc! BTW, the robust statistical estimator can trap into severe situation where noise is local and globally affect the observation and it surfers from lacking bagging features. Generally you should first understand the characteristics of the data in hand then decide what would be sufficient path to take for such problem!